# Profile WatchKit App Extension with Xcode 8 and watchOS3

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch, beta, xcode8-beta6

I want to *profile* my app which is also available for Apple Watch. I'm currently using the latest Beta of Xcode 8 and watchOS3.0 (Beta 6).

Xcode has this great tool included called "Instruments" where you can debug your app and see which functions need the most CPU time etc.

This tool works great when *profiling* on my iPhone. But if I want to profile my WatchKit Extension, it's not working. It always tells me "Waiting for Xcode to download symbols":

[image]

But Xcode is **NOT** downloading anything! I also added the path to Instruments where to search symbol files:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug or is it me? I tried everything but I can't get this thing to work ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the directory "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/watchOS DeviceSupport/" will be one or more Watch directories. One of them will be for your version of the watch. Inside of that subdirectory, create an empty "Info.plist" file and then restart Instruments.

Comment: Thank you! That really worked! Can you explain why, please?

Comment: 2 days of banging my head against a wall later... Thanks!